# Parse.com unpinInBackground doesn't work

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

It's very simple flow that we are implementing. First pin an item:

```
 object.pinInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
         @Override
         public void done(ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {
                    // success
                } else {
                    // error
                }
          }
 });
```

Then later on I unpin it:

```
object.unpinInBackground(new DeleteCallback() {
    @Override
    public void done(ParseException e) {
          mObjects.remove(object);
          mObjectsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
});
```

But! When I get to check the local datastore, like this:

```
ParseQuery<Object> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Object");
query.fromLocalDatastore().findInBackground(new FindCallback<Object>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<Object> objects, ParseException e) {
                // list of object contains the unpined object!
        }
});
```

The list of objects contains all unpined objects from before!

Is this something that I am doing wrong, not understand or there is some bug in Parse.com?

Answer (score 1):

For me the answer was I invoked saveEventually().
When use saveEventually() the problem is object can't disappear until we will be online. But then object fly to server - will be not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Going off [this](https://www.parse.com/questions/unpin-a-specific-parse-object-from-localdatastore-by-its-position-in-a-queryadapter-returns-null).

You may need to do this:

```
object.unpinInBackground("Object Name", new DeleteCallback() {
    public void done(ParseException e) {
        if (e == null) {
            // successful
        } 
        else {
            // unsuccessful
        }
    }
 });
```

You need to specify the name of the object you are trying to unpin.

Answer (score 0):

you can't unpin an object that has a referenced object

Probably you have another object which has a reference to the object you want to delete.

So you will have to delete those first.